# Google Line Chart not displaying MySQL query using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, charts, google-visualization

Hi StackOverflow community, I am struggling to display a MySQL query using PHP in a Google Line chart. The problem is the Line Chart isn't displaying.
I'd be grateful to anyone who would be able to point me in the right direction. The following MySQL query is what I'm trying to represent in the line chart:

```
SELECT
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`) AS `Date`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 0,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 1,
    1,
    0)) AS `OneAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 2,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoAM`, 
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 3,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreeAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 4,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 5,
    1,
    0)) AS `FiveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 6,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 7,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 8,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 9,
    1,
    0)) AS `NineAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 10,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 11,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 12,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelvePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 13,
    1,
    0)) AS `OnePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 14,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 15,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 16,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 17,
    1,
    0)) AS `FivePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 18,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 19,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 20,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 21,
    1,
    0)) AS `NinePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 22,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 23,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenPM`
FROM
    `jurl_analytics`
WHERE
    `URL_ID` = 'westonsupermare'
GROUP BY
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`)
LIMIT 7
```

The following query displays the number of requests per hour for the last 7 days.
[image: Output of the query in PHPMyAdmin]

I wish to represent this data in a Google Line Chart like the following image:
[image]

This is what I've tried:
//If you decide to create the database please fill the server, username, password and database fields.

```
 <?php
    $server = ""; 
    $username = ""; 
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
    if ($connect)
    {
        echo "You are connected!". "<br>";
    }

function runAndCheckSQL($connection, $sql){
    $run = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($run) {
        if(is_array($run) || is_object($run)){
            
            return $run;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        die(showError($sql, $connection));
    }
}
$sevenDaysHours = "SELECT
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`) AS `Date`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 0,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 1,
    1,
    0)) AS `OneAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 2,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoAM`, 
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 3,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreeAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 4,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 5,
    1,
    0)) AS `FiveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 6,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 7,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 8,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 9,
    1,
    0)) AS `NineAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 10,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 11,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 12,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelvePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 13,
    1,
    0)) AS `OnePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 14,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 15,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 16,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 17,
    1,
    0)) AS `FivePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 18,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 19,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 20,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 21,
    1,
    0)) AS `NinePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 22,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 23,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenPM`
FROM
    `jurl_analytics`
WHERE
    `URL_ID` = 'westonsupermare'
GROUP BY
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`)
LIMIT 7"
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', 'ThreeAM', 'FourAM', 'FiveAM', 'SixAM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM'],
      <?php
        
        $fire = mysqli_query($connect, $sevenDaysHours);
        
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire))
        {
            echo "['".$result['Date']."',".$result['TwelveAM']."',".$result['OneAM']."',".$result['TwoAM']."',".$result['ThreeAM']."',".$result['FourAM']."',".$result['FiveAM']."',".$result['SixAM']."',".$result['SevenAM']."',".$result['EightAM']."',".$result['NineAM']."',".$result['TenAM']."',".$result['ElevenAM']."',".$result['TwelvePM']."',".$result['OnePM']."',".$result['TwoPM']."',".$result['ThreePM']."',".$result['FourPM']."',".$result['FivePM']."',".$result['SixPM']."',".$result['SevenPM']."',".$result['EightPM']."',".$result['NinePM']."',".$result['TenPM']."',".$result['ElevenPM']."',".$result['TwelvePM']."],";
        }
        ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

To create the database to help with the solution for this problem, please run the following to create the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `JURL_Analytics` (
  `VISIT_ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `VISIT_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `JURL_Analytics` (`VISIT_ID`, `VISIT_TIME`) VALUES
(705, '2020-08-26 15:20:26'),
(704, '2020-08-26 13:19:08'),
(703, '2020-08-25 21:40:22'),
(702, '2020-08-25 17:34:29'),
(701, '2020-08-25 17:34:23'),
(700, '2020-08-25 10:12:39'),
(699, '2020-08-25 09:26:57'),
(698, '2020-08-25 09:26:57'),
(697, '2020-08-25 09:26:32'),
(696, '2020-08-25 09:22:43'),
(695, '2020-08-25 09:18:58'),
(694, '2020-08-25 09:12:25'),
(693, '2020-08-24 16:18:45'),
(692, '2020-08-24 14:22:20'),
(691, '2020-08-24 14:19:39'),
(690, '2020-08-24 14:19:03'),
(689, '2020-08-24 13:48:00'),
(688, '2020-08-24 06:21:50'),
(687, '2020-08-23 20:22:26'),
(686, '2020-08-23 19:55:26'),
(685, '2020-08-23 19:54:09'),
(684, '2020-08-23 07:34:47'),
(683, '2020-08-22 23:28:29'),
(682, '2020-08-22 13:24:44'),
(681, '2020-08-22 09:56:58'),
(680, '2020-08-22 06:54:50'),
(679, '2020-08-22 06:53:37'),
(678, '2020-08-22 03:13:39'),
(677, '2020-08-22 03:11:30'),
(676, '2020-08-21 16:47:31'),
(675, '2020-08-20 18:13:02'),
(674, '2020-08-20 17:28:48'),
(673, '2020-08-20 10:57:27'),
(672, '2020-08-19 15:21:29'),
(671, '2020-08-19 14:57:21'),
(670, '2020-08-19 10:25:26'),
(669, '2020-08-18 18:53:22'),
(668, '2020-08-18 18:04:46'),
(667, '2020-08-18 18:00:13'),
(666, '2020-08-18 17:59:59'),
(665, '2020-08-18 14:35:04'),
(664, '2020-08-18 11:49:22'),
(663, '2020-08-18 11:43:47'),
(662, '2020-08-18 11:25:02'),
(661, '2020-08-18 08:07:09'),
(660, '2020-08-18 07:57:51'),
(659, '2020-08-18 01:09:30'),
(658, '2020-08-17 21:43:36'),
(657, '2020-08-17 21:43:07'),
(656, '2020-08-17 20:53:50'),
(655, '2020-08-17 20:15:12'),
(654, '2020-08-17 18:08:16')
```

What I've tried in response to DroopSnoot:

```
echo "['".$result['Date']."',".$result['TwelveAM']."','".$result['OneAM']."','".$result['TwoAM']."','".$result['ThreeAM']."','".$result['FourAM']."','".$result['FiveAM']."','".$result['SixAM']."','".$result['SevenAM']."','".$result['EightAM']."','".$result['NineAM']."','".$result['TenAM']."','".$result['ElevenAM']."','".$result['TwelvePM']."','".$result['OnePM']."','".$result['TwoPM']."','".$result['ThreePM']."','".$result['FourPM']."','".$result['FivePM']."','".$result['SixPM']."','".$result['SevenPM']."','".$result['EightPM']."','".$result['NinePM']."','".$result['TenPM']."','".$result['ElevenPM']."','".$result['TwelvePM']."],";
```

What I'm getting from WhiteHat's answer:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what problems are you getting?

Comment: The problem the Line Chart isn't displaying when I've written everything according to the manual. And logically it should work I've spent many hours alas! to no avail. I am coming to StackOverflow as a last resort.

Comment: DO NOT try and create JSON manually. Fill the appropriate data structure in PHP, and then use `json_encode` to create the proper output.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I'm not sure JSON is the problem.

Comment: So far you don’t seem to be sure where the problem is _at all_ - so at least exclude that as a potential error reason, but doing it “the right way” to begin with.

Comment: The problem is that the Chart isn't displaying in Google Chrome. And it does work if I have only two collumns which is strange, but any more than that it just doesn't display. Do you have an explanation for this? I'm really wanting this to work.

Comment: The placement of single quotes in that echo line in your while loop is totally off. If I replace every single occurrence of one of the `$result[…]` fields in there with `$result['foo']`, and then provide a value of `$result['foo'] = 123;` for that, the result is `['123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123',123],` - you are not telling me your browser error console had nothing to say about that?

Comment: They're not arbitrary! They're getting extracted from a MYSQL query using aliases.

Comment: I think the point is the surrounding single-quotes, you have many that close but weren't opened. `echo "['".$result['Date']."',".$result['TwelveAM']."',"` there is no opening single-quote before the second variable, but there is a closing one after it.

Comment: Your function `drawChart` first echoes all the JSON data and then calls `chart.draw(data, options);` Is that the correct order? Perhaps the `echo` statement should be instead appending the data to the `data` array.

Comment: Can I be honest? I find it so difficult to follow the syntax to how it should be done. As it's so easy to misplace quotes, commas, and apostrophes. I don't suppose you could correct it and I could try it? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Also, I got the chart from Google Charts.https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html I did not write that myself. I really desperately want this to work. I've tried everything! :(

Comment: The bit of code I quoted above should read `echo "['".$result['Date']."','".$result['TwelveAM']."','"` - can you see the difference? An extra open single-quote between the two variables, and another at the end of the quoted bit because there's another variable coming after it. First off you need to make sure you close and open all on that line. I've shown the first part, you can do the rest.

Comment: The point is, if you take away the rest of the collumns and leave just the Date and TwelveAM ones, it works! However, when I add any more than that the chart just doesn't display in Google Chrome.

Comment: And by the way, I find it so confusing with the amount of commas and apostrophes and whatnot. I am really sorry!

Comment: droopsnoot, I have just edited my question to show you that I have added what you suggested yet it still doesn't work. Can you have a look at it for me and tell me if I have missed anything? It's right at the end. Would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few issues here.

first, you have 25 values in the column headings...

```
['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', ...
```

but 26 values in the row data...

```
echo "['".$result['Date']."',".$result['TwelveAM']."','".$result['OneAM']."' ...
```

there are two `TwelvePM` values, we'll remove the one at the very end,
since it doesn't match the last column heading.

---

next, as you mentioned in your comment,
the *amount of commas and apostrophes* can be confusing.
this is one of the reasons you should not try to build the JSON manually.

instead, build the array in PHP, then encode the JSON when writing to the page.

```
<?php
  $data = array();
  $data[] = ['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', 'ThreeAM', 'FourAM', 'FiveAM', 'SixAM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM'];

  $fire = mysqli_query($connect, $sevenDaysHours);
  while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire))
  {
    $data[] = [$result['Date'], $result['TwelveAM'], $result['OneAM'], $result['TwoAM'], $result['ThreeAM'], $result['FourAM'], $result['FiveAM'], $result['SixAM'], $result['SevenAM'], $result['EightAM'], $result['NineAM'], $result['TenAM'], $result['ElevenAM'], $result['TwelvePM'], $result['OnePM'], $result['TwoPM'], $result['ThreePM'], $result['FourPM'], $result['FivePM'], $result['SixPM'], $result['SevenPM'], $result['EightPM'], $result['NinePM'], $result['TenPM'], $result['ElevenPM']];
  }
?>

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

---

here's the part you're looking for...

```
<?php
  $server = "";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $database = "";
  $connect = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
  if ($connect)
  {
      echo "You are connected!". "<br>";
  }

  function runAndCheckSQL($connection, $sql){
    $run = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($run) {
        if(is_array($run) || is_object($run)){

            return $run;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        die(showError($sql, $connection));
    }
  }

  $sevenDaysHours = "SELECT
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`) AS `Date`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 0,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 1,
    1,
    0)) AS `OneAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 2,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 3,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreeAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 4,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 5,
    1,
    0)) AS `FiveAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 6,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 7,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 8,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 9,
    1,
    0)) AS `NineAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 10,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 11,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenAM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 12,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwelvePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 13,
    1,
    0)) AS `OnePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 14,
    1,
    0)) AS `TwoPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 15,
    1,
    0)) AS `ThreePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 16,
    1,
    0)) AS `FourPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 17,
    1,
    0)) AS `FivePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 18,
    1,
    0)) AS `SixPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 19,
    1,
    0)) AS `SevenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 20,
    1,
    0)) AS `EightPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 21,
    1,
    0)) AS `NinePM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 22,
    1,
    0)) AS `TenPM`,
    SUM(IF(HOUR(`VISIT_TIME`) = 23,
    1,
    0)) AS `ElevenPM`
  FROM
    `jurl_analytics`
  WHERE
    `URL_ID` = 'westonsupermare'
  GROUP BY
    DATE(`VISIT_TIME`)
  LIMIT 7"
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  <?php
    $data = array();
    $data[] = ['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', 'ThreeAM', 'FourAM', 'FiveAM', 'SixAM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM'];

    $fire = mysqli_query($connect, $sevenDaysHours);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire))
    {
      $data[] = [$result['Date'], $result['TwelveAM'], $result['OneAM'], $result['TwoAM'], $result['ThreeAM'], $result['FourAM'], $result['FiveAM'], $result['SixAM'], $result['SevenAM'], $result['EightAM'], $result['NineAM'], $result['TenAM'], $result['ElevenAM'], $result['TwelvePM'], $result['OnePM'], $result['TwoPM'], $result['ThreePM'], $result['FourPM'], $result['FivePM'], $result['SixPM'], $result['SevenPM'], $result['EightPM'], $result['NinePM'], $result['TenPM'], $result['ElevenPM']];
    }
  ?>

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

if the numeric values come across as strings from PHP,
then try adding the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` parameter to the encode statement.

```
<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
```

let's assign the JSON data to its own variable.
then we can send the result to the console for inspection.
if it still doesn't work, please share a sample from the console.

```
<?php
  $data = array();
  $data[] = ['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', 'ThreeAM', 'FourAM', 'FiveAM', 'SixAM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM'];

  $fire = mysqli_query($connect, $sevenDaysHours);
  while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire))
  {
    $data[] = [$result['Date'], $result['TwelveAM'], $result['OneAM'], $result['TwoAM'], $result['ThreeAM'], $result['FourAM'], $result['FiveAM'], $result['SixAM'], $result['SevenAM'], $result['EightAM'], $result['NineAM'], $result['TenAM'], $result['ElevenAM'], $result['TwelvePM'], $result['OnePM'], $result['TwoPM'], $result['ThreePM'], $result['FourPM'], $result['FivePM'], $result['SixPM'], $result['SevenPM'], $result['EightPM'], $result['NinePM'], $result['TenPM'], $result['ElevenPM']];
  }
?>

var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

in order to get the desired chart,
we need to swap the columns for rows and vice-versa.
this will most likely be too difficult to achieve by changing the query.
but we can easily create a new data table in JavaScript.

so, pretty much leave everything the same.
except we will add the following routine to create a new data table,
with the columns and rows swapped.
then use the new data table to draw the chart.

```
var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

  // create new data table with columns and rows swapped
  var dataHours = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataHours.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
  for (var row = 0; row < data.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
    var dateColumn = dataHours.addColumn('number', data.getValue(row, 0));
    for (var col = 1; col < data.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
      var dateRow = dataHours.addRow();
      dataHours.setValue(dateRow, 0, col);
      dataHours.setValue(dateRow, dateColumn, data.getValue(row, col));
    }
  }

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(dataHours, options);  // <-- draw chart with new data table
}
```

following is a working example, showing before and after the swap...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'TwelveAM', 'OneAM', 'TwoAM', 'ThreeAM', 'FourAM', 'FiveAM', 'SixAM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM'],
    ['2020-08-14', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
    ['2020-08-15', 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50],
    ['2020-08-16', 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75],
    ['2020-08-17', 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96, 100]
  ]);

  // create new data table with columns and rows swapped  
  var dataHours = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataHours.addColumn('number', 'Hour');
  for (var row = 0; row < data.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
    var dateColumn = dataHours.addColumn('number', data.getValue(row, 0));
    for (var col = 1; col < data.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
      var dateRow = dataHours.addRow();
      dataHours.setValue(dateRow, 0, col);
      dataHours.setValue(dateRow, dateColumn, data.getValue(row, col));
    }
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 64,
      top: 48,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 64,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      alignment: 'center',
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chartBefore = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_before'));
  chartBefore.draw(data, options);

  var chartAfter = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_after'));
  chartAfter.draw(dataHours, options);
});
```

```css
.chart {
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart_before"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart_after"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, if it still doesn't work. you need to press F12 in google chrome to open the dev tools. then find the console tab at the top, and provide any messages displayed in red. these are errors...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer by the way! I feel now I'm at least getting somewhere. I am getting displayed in Google Chrome  
Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string× Do you know what could be causing this message? I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Comment: this means that the values for the y-axis are coming from php as strings, instead of numbers. see edit above, we'll assign the data to its own variable. then we can send to the console to inspect. please share a sample of the result from the console.

Comment: Hi WhiteHat! Thank you so much first of all, it now finally works! However, this wasn't how I was imagining the graph to look. I have edited my question and have included a picture of the result. I am very sorry to keep going on as you've helped me incredibly, is it possible to make adjustments so it looks and feels like the graph I said I wanted it to look like originally?

Comment: that might require another question, but let's take a look. so it appears you want the hours on the x-axis and each date to be a series (line). correct?

Comment: That is correct! I am so sorry for this by the way, I'm just wondering if it would be an easy fix. I feel I'm pushing my luck so much as you've helped me greatly!

Comment: I certainly will! I am very grateful that you're helping me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220562/discussion-between-george-austin-bradley-and-whitehat).